# Opposing Definitions of the Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation,

The wave equation is defined as

$$
\Big(\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Big)u(r,t) = 0,
$$

where $r$ represents the spatial variable.  If I assume that I'm working with a one-dimensional string and that $\nabla^2 = \Delta$, then I should be able to write the above instead as

$$
\Big(\Delta - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Big)u(x,t) = 0,
$$

and I've done the following algebraic manipulations:

$$
\Delta(u,t) - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u(x,t) = 0
$$
$$
\Delta(u,t) - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = 0
$$
$$
\Big(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \Big) - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = -\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\Big(1 - \frac{1}{c^2} \Big) = -\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\Big( \frac{c^2 - 1}{c^2} \Big) = -\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{c^2}{c^2 - 1}\Big(-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} \Big)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = \Big(\frac{c^2}{1 - c^2} \Big)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},
$$

however this contradicts with the definition of the wave equation that I've been taught, which is

$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}.
$$

The main difference being that in the first derived wave equation above, $\frac{c^2}{1-c^2}$ may not always be a positive number (like, if c > 1) whereas in the definition that I am familiar with the constant $c^2$ must always be positive regardless of the value of $c$.

Am I misinterpreting the the very first equation, doing something wrong in my algebraic manipulations or perhaps misinterpreting the wave equation being defined in the referenced link (perhaps it can't be used when spatial dimension is just one)?

Comment: The $\Delta$ in the given wave equation is only acting on the spatial coordinates, so it doesn't include the time partial.

Comment: In general $\nabla^2= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $ where $r=(x_i)$. You do not include the time derivative.

Comment: @DogeChan Typo? $\nabla^2= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$

Comment: So what you're saying is that $\Delta u(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$, rather than $\Delta u(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}$?

Comment: @Oderus Yes.  I actually prefer the notation $\Delta_xu(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ or more generally $\Delta_xu(\mathbf{x},t) = \sum \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i{}^2}$ instead, but it's just a notational issue rather than anything deeper.